# Rename a file to combine the names of two files

Tags: java, file-io

I have the following files in my filesystem: `file1_mp4` and `file2_3gp`.

I want to rename the second file to the name of the left half of the first file `file1` and the extension `_3gp` from the second file, producing `file1_3gp`.

Comment: Can you do that in bash?

Comment: i want it from inside my java program

Answer (score 3):

Since the underscore is not actually an extension separator, you'd have to split the name:

```
String[] parts1 = file1.getName().split("_");
String[] parts2 = file2.getName().split("_");
```

Then you can rename

```
file1.renameTo(parts1[0] + "_" + parts2[1]);
```

(above, `file1` and `file2` are instances of `java.io.File`)

Comment: Better use "lastIndexOf" and "substring" to split the names yourself, because the file path may contain more underscores.

Answer (score 0):

To rename file use [renameTo()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#renameTo%28java.io.File%29) method of `File` class. Use methods of `String` class to manipulate their names.